# Selecting nodes that don't contain any children with given text()?

Tags: xml, xpath

Given this XML fragment:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <strong>Specifications</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Finish</td>
      <td>Black</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Action</td>
      <td>Semi-Automatic</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Caliber</td>
      <td>7.62mmX39mm</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm trying to select all `tr` elements that do not contain the text `Specifications` anywhere below themselves, but I'm horrid at XPath and can't get it right.  I tried

```
//table/tbody/tr[not(contains(text(),'Specifications'))]
```

but that clearly is still giving me the `tr` node containing `Specifications`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Requested XPath:**

```
/table/tbody/tr[not(.//text()[contains(.,'Specifications')])]
```

**Sample test program:**

```
<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <xsl:copy-of select="/table/tbody/tr[not(.//text()[contains(.,'Specifications')])]"/>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**Output given your input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Finish</td>
         <td>Black</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Action</td>
         <td>Semi-Automatic</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Caliber</td>
         <td>7.62mmX39mm</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

//table/tbody/tr[not(contains(td, 'Specifications'))] # bad one

//table/tbody/tr[not(contains(., 'Specifications'))] # better

Comment: i use scrapy.selector.HtmlXPathSelector, and it is part of my working program.I tested and upvoted your answer, it is better.

Comment: @kjhughes, why is `//table/tbody/tr[not(contains(td, 'Specifications'))]` wrong? When I test it using XPath 1.0 on http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html or XPath 2.0 on http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi , it selects the correct nodes. `//table/tbody/tr[not(contains(., 'Specifications'))]`

Comment: @pault, in XPath 1.0, it appears to work for the given input only because XPath 1.0 has `contains()` converting the first node in the nodeset of its first argument to text.  Place another `<td>trouble</td>` before the `td` that contains "Specifications" to see the issue.  XPath 2.0 will complain that a sequence of more than one item isn't allowed in the first argument of `contains()` whereas XPath 1.0, due to "first item semantics," will select the `tr` whose second `td` contains "Specification", contrary to the requested results.

Comment: Thanks @kjhughes. I tested with XPath 2.0 on http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi with standard XQuary compatibility (XPath 1.0 compatibility is on by default, so that disables it I guess) and indeed there's an "invalid types" error for `contains()`. `//table/tbody/tr[not(contains(., 'Specifications'))]` would work though, even in XPath 2.0 from what I can test online (I don't have an XPath 2.0 tool)